# Can't figure out why @property doesn't work

Tags: python

The following code doesn't work properly. `setlen` isn't called from this line `a.length=10`

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,length=0):
        self._length=length
        self._area=length**2

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._area

    def getlen(self):
        return self._length

    def setlen(self,x):
        self._length=x
        self.area=x**2

    length=property(getlen, setlen)

a=A()
a.length=10
print a.area
```

Comment: With `def area(self)` returning `self._length**2`, you don't need a setter for `length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on Python 2.x. Classes need to inherit from `object`, directly or through the inheritance chain, for most of the newer features of the class system to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using the decorator form one time and not the other. Better to use it both times:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,length=0):
        self._length=length
        self._area=length**2

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._area

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def setlen(self,x):
        self._length=x
        self.area=x**2
```

Although as user2357112 says, the root of the problem is that you are not inheriting from `object`.

Comment: Maybe they're making sure they're writing 2.5 compatible code :)

Comment: I get `File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    a.length=10
AttributeError: can't set attribute` with `@length.setter`.

Comment: nevermind I fixed it by having the name of the function the same as `length`